# Is there any way to set iPhone wallpaper programmatically in iOS 4.2 (beta)

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2

I know this question has been asked before, but does anyone know if its possible to programmatically set the background image for the home screen (wallpaper) for the latest iphone OS *iOS4.2 (beta)*. I know it wasn't possible before.

I've seen that you can change the lock screen on a jailbroken phone by writing to /var/mobile/Library/LockBackground.jpg, can you do the same for the home screen wallpaper?

Follow up: as the commenters pointed out, iOS 4.2 is under NDA, so I rephrase the question for 4.1?

Comment: iOS 4.2 beta is under NDA.  Use the devforums at developer.apple.com....

Comment: iOS SDK 4.2 beta, iOS 4.2 beta, Mac OS X v10.6.5 and Xcode 4 developer preview are pre-release software and are considered Apple Confidential Information.

Comment: Thanks, I sent an email to the tech support at Apple, and I'll post over a the apple dev forum. I'm pretty confident the answer is no, and I don't want to go down the jail-breaking road but just wanted to get a feel for all the options.

Comment: I answered a similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38993774/119114). Note: solution isn't appropriate for the App Store, but it does *not* actually require jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2):

No.  And are you sure it's in /var/mobile/Library???  When I do

```
    NSArray *test = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Library/"];
```

I don't get a LockBackground.jpg file.  Also, You can NOT write to /var/mobile/Library (using `writeToFile:atomically:`)

Note: I am doing this under 4.1

Comment: Thanks for trying that, so if the file is there its not writable - which I guess makes sense. Its probably a bad idea to go around the SDK anyway...