# How to set lock screen , wallpaper and Ringtone programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios4, iphone-privateapi

In iPhone can we set the lock screen, wallpaper and ringtone programmatically?

If **Yes**, then please let me know how to set them?

Comment: +1 I seen it in many apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024361/add-image-on-lock-screen-in-ios-app-when-app-is-running-in-background

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can all be done easily, but will be rejected by Apple.

The ringtone can be changed by altering `com.apple.SpringBoard.plist`, specifically the `ringtone` key.

The following code can be used to read the actual ringtone title of custom ringtones (synced by iTunes).

```
NSMutableDictionary *custDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/Ringtones.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [custDict objectForKey:@"Ringtones"];

NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
id key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableDictionary *customRingtone = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
NSString *name = [customRingtone objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

The Wallpapers can be overwritten at:

```
NSString *homePath1 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackground.jpg";
NSString *homePath2 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackgroundPortrait.jpg";
NSString *lockPath1 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.jpg";
NSString *lockPath2 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackgroundPortrait.jpg";
```

These examples were used in one of my Cydia apps. Theres not really much more to them, but these should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Wallpaper paths are no longer valid.

Comment: No need for the down vote. They were valid at the time the question was asked and chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: I cant tell you the new path, but I can tell you that apple uses a new image formate. Its a cpbitmap, so if you like tomsave the image you first need to convert the .png or .jpeg to a .cpbitmap

Comment: @WrightsCS Could you please update with the new paths for iOS 9.x ?

Comment: how to change programmatically  change ringtone objective c

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by WrightsCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4476831/119114) stopped working at some point due to a change in iOS. Unfortunately, this is something you have to live with if you wish to use *undocumented* features.

If you still need to do this, **for non-App Store apps only**, this code works in iOS 9.3. It could stop working in any future iOS release, though. *(see comment below: no longer working in iOS 10)*

```
#import "SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController.h"
#import <dlfcn.h>

// open the private framework dynamically
void *handle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUIServices.framework/SpringBoardUIServices", RTLD_NOW);

UIImage *wallpaper = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.jpg"];

Class sbClass = NSClassFromString(@"SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController");
// we create a view controller, but don't display it. 
//  just use it to load image and set wallpaper
SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController *controller = (SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController*)[[sbClass alloc] initWithImage: wallpaper];
[controller setWallpaperForLocations: 3];  // 3 -> set both for lock screen and home screen

dlclose(handle);
```

You'll need to add the private API header to your project. You can usually find these online with a little searching, [for example, here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUIServices.framework/SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController.h).

In the example above, `[SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController setWallpaperForLocations:]` is called with an argument of 3: 3 indicates the image should be used for **both** lock and home screens. 1 indicates Lock screen only. 2 indicates Home screen only.

---

For an explanation of why I open this framework up *dynamically*, see [my related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001091/119114).

I don't have an answer regarding **ringtones**. This really should be a separate question: completely different APIs at work.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on iOS 10 anymore. @Nate do you have info how to get this running on iOS 10?  (For iOS 10  his code crashes with error:
Assertion failed: (0), function SBSUIWallpaperClearVideo, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/SpringBoardUIServices/SpringBoard-3563.15.8.9/SBSUIWallpaperUtilities.m, line 143.) Probably they added some smart asserts... )

Comment: @GuntisTreulands, yes I noticed that, too. I'm looking at [iOS 10 headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUIServices.framework/SBSUIWallpaperPreviewViewController.h) and it looks like the API is still there. Might be protected by entitlement, now. I do remember in the past finding other ways to do this, so let me spend some time this weekend trying other things to get this working.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands, I also tried using the similar method in `PLStaticWallpaperImageViewController`, but it also failed. It looks like iOS recognizes that the app is trying to change something outside its sandbox. I also see there's another API in [PhotoLibrary](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PLWallpaperImageViewController.h), but I have to do some reverse engineering to figure out what the parameter it takes is. I will keep you updated here.

Answer (score 1):

use private api if you can
check `PLStaticWallpaperImageViewController`