# Can you modify the iphone password screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way I could make an application to add a button to the lock screen (enter your password)? For iOS/iPhone devices?

Comment: My idea is not to do the password screen over, I just want to add a button to the password screen that would do something.

Comment: No, it's private sdk, but I think you can add something to the "Slide to open" screen.

Comment: I was poking fun.  There probably isn't a way to do it.

Comment: If it is not on jailbroken devices, you cannot do it. Even you technically achieved it, you will be rejected for sure since Apple specifically said they hate people modified the look of iOS(anything)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically changing the iOS lock-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I could make an application to add a button to the lock screen

No, I don't believe that there's a public API for that sort of thing. Apple can obviously do it, since the iPad lock screen has a button that shows you a photo gallery. But that doesn't mean that third party applications have that capability, and I'd be very surprised if you could pull that off without jailbreaking your device.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is outside of your applications sandbox. Unless you jailbreak the device, there is no way to run outside the application sandbox(with minor exceptions such as playing music).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is against the sandbox policy.

Answer (score 0):

NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

but there are apps in cydia that do this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

To be simple, there is no such API to make customizations on the iOS itself. Neither does Apple allow it.