# Add a button to the lockscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just want to add a button to the lockscreen, I know that `SBAwayController` manage the lock screen, and they have a SBAwayView* that have all the views, and using MSHook... I get the *_awayView
so how can I add a button, for example in the middle of the screen ?

Comment: There is an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen

Comment: Create the object of UIButton and add it as subview to the `_awayView`. Are you getting any error or something. Please try to explain your question more.

Comment: But dont forget that if you go for a change on the lockscreen like this you can not add your app to the normal app store, because apple will reject your app for sure!

Comment: Yes u know that is not possible to summit to the app store, is just for learning. But _awayView is not a UIView object, is a SBAwayView object, so addSubView is not possible right? Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: it is a subclass of UIView so addSubview should be there

Comment: Instead of presuming that it will not work, I suggest to give it a try before. Furthermore, simplest use of breakpoints would have proofed your assumption wrong. Maybe you should do your homework before you try to use a private, not well documented and fast altering API.