# Is it possible to add button to iphone lock screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to add a button on Iphone lock screen which on tap will open the app.Is it possible to do so? If possible, how? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189691/add-a-button-to-the-lockscreen) link but don't understand. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen
Take a look here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no, that's not possible, Apple don't allow you to add to the lock screen.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it requires private APIs and won't be approved for the App Store.