# Changing lock screen wallpaper iphone programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, wallpaper, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically changing the iOS lock-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen)

I am new to iphone, I want to know whether i can change my iphone lock screen wallpaper programmatically through application.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean (a) by writing an application yourself or (b) an existing app?

Answer (score 5):

`NO` You can not change iPhone Lock screen wallpaper programatically. (Except Jailbroken phones)