# Is it possible to create an iOS app that can show some clickable elements on lockscreen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, lockscreen

i want to develope an iOS app, which has some clickable elements that user migth interact with, without unlocking the iphone, similiary to mediaplayers. So some clickable elements on the lockscreen.

Comment: You cannot add control on the lock screen, you however create a widgets that can be accessed from the lock screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, no unless you don't want to submit your app to the official app store. see here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243591/programatically-changing-the-ios-lock-screen)

Comment: are there some tutorials for that ?

Comment: @user993074 if you are asking for widgets, it is on [apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html)

Comment: okay, thanks for the answer :)