# Set Home Screen Image Programmatically in iOS Device

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, homescreen

I am developing an application which allow user to take photo and can set the photo as home screen image?

In case if the device is Jail breaked any solutions?

thanks in advance

Comment: Answered [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38993774/119114).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the background image pragmatically and there are no APIs to do this. Your only option is to save an image to the users' Photos and then tell them that they can set it from there.