# An app that will show emergency Contacts on lock screen

Tags: ios, iphone, lockscreen

I have been researching regarding showing some emergency contacts on lock screen in IOS but did not get any help regarding this.

Basically i want to create an app that will show emergency contact number on lock screen that can be useful in case if some one is injured or lost the phone. Like it can be someone's family contact number. In case someone who is injured is unconscious then helper can contact the family.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show anything on the lock screen (unless you have a jailbroken device). What you *could* do though, is create a [Today widget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html). The Today screen is accessible from the lock screen, without unlocking the iPhone.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to make a call without unlocking the phone - I haven't tested this however

Comment: You're right about this, but you could always do this with your own phone.

Comment: But how this app managed to do this, refer the link :-


https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ice-in-case-of-emergency/id380234187?mt=8

Comment: Ah, they just create an image, and ask the user to select it as a wallpaper on the lock screen (there is no way to do that programmatically, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476777/how-to-set-lock-screen-wallpaper-and-ringtone-programmatically-in-iphone)).